# Concatenating address field in formula

Tags: formula-field, data-types

I don't know if the subject resume my problem . I would like to display in my HTML page the name of Supplier with adress . 
on HTML something like that :

```
<span> Supplier Name <br/> Supplier Adress  </span>
```

when I try to create a field as a formula type and edit this as a formula .

```
Account__r.Name + BR()+ Account__r.BillingAddress
```

the result is an error message like this

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Location

Note that the formula return type is text.

Comment: You may wish to view [this.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) Seems that addresses are their own type and, as such, will need you to break them apart before adding them to a string.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Visualforce page simply write:

```
<span> {!Account__r.Name} <br/> {!Account__r.BillingAddress} </span>
```

I doubt `Account__r.BillingAddress` may create error for you. Let me know. You can also try

```
<span> {!Account__r.Name} <br/> <apex:outputText> value="{!Account__r.BillingAddress}"/> </span>
```

Comment: I think the problem is BillingAddress is adress  data type . I try  to change visualforce ' <p > {!relatedTo.Account__r.BillingAddress} </p> but the error is 'Error: Unsupported type: common.api.soap.wsdl.Address used in expression: relatedTo.Account__r.BillingAddress' . When I try with BillinCity (data type text) it works ' <p > {!relatedTo.Account__r.BillingCity } </p>' so the problem is how to retrieve the value of adress and phone type .

Comment: Refer to following link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#topic-title It has all API names which you need. Phone fields has the API name `Phone` so you can reference it as `{!Account__r.Phone}` @JulioLudovicRamihone

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
Account__r.Name + BR()+ Account__r.BillingStreet+ BR() + Account__r.BillingCity + BR() +....
```

to build up the full address.

Address fields are a special case in Salesforce and are a concatenation of the underlying data fields. Selecting each individually can get around errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

this code solve the proble , the formula is correct but when we display it , we use .

```
<apex:outputText> value="{!Account__r.BillingAddress}"/>
```

thanks a lot